# Invalid JSON syntax error in configuration file on homebridge

Tags: json, config

```
{
   "bridge":{
      "name":"Homebridge F8F5",
      "username":"0E:8F:12:8D:F8:F5",
      "port":51739,
      "pin":"670-48-238"
   },
   "accessories":[
      
   ],
   "platforms":[
      {
         "name":"Config",
         "port":8581,
         "platform":"config"
      }
   ]
}{
   "accessories":[
      {
         "name":"Roku",
         "accessory":"Roku",
         "ip":"http://10.204.1.238:8060",

}
```

I am getting an error when I try to run this config file in homebridge. What am I doing wrong? When I try to submit it through the web interface it will not allow me to and says “Config JSON error: invalid json syntax” Any help will be welcome! I have tried  to put it through an online json error finder and it narrowed it down to this snippet.

Comment: Is this your entire JSON file? If so, it has two root elements, which is not legal JSON.

Comment: This is not my entire json file. Can you explain this? This is my first time working with json. https://gist.github.com/NoahBlaut/165443cb6273f262f77ec47e5d6e20e4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ummm... looks like you tried to edit this file without knowing the basic concepts of JSON.

Start by reading [JSON - Introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) on W2Schools.com

Also, if you're not sure, use an online JSON validator.  Use your fav. search engine to look for ***"JSON cleaner"***.  *(I use [JSON Formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#) at Curious Concept.)*

Off the bat I can see a few issues with the JSON you provided.

1. the "`}{`" string ... what's that for?  JSON cannot parse that ... either add "`,`" between *(if you wanted a new set)* or *(in this case)* remove it.
2. you have two `"accessories"`. JSON usually get parsed into an object or array ... one cannot have duplicates on the ket names. *(In this case)* remove the first one.
3. the second `"accessories"` array *(denoted by "`[`")* has no end *(no "`]`")*
4. the whole set *(started with "`{`")* has no end *(no "`}`")*